# docker-compose проблема с доступом из вне

Tags: ubuntu, docker, iptables, docker-compose

Добрый день , есть проблема , надо закрыть доступ ко всем контейнерам из мира кроме локалхоста.

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'

    network_mode: "host"

    volumes:
          - /bitnami/mongo:/bitnami

    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"

    environment:
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123

  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'

    network_mode: "host"

    volumes:
          - /bitnami/redis:/bitnami

    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:6379:6379'

    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=password123

  main:
    build: .

    network_mode: "host"

    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"

    volumes:
     - .:/code
     - /settings:/go/settings/
```

Вот там root@localhost:~# netstat -plnt

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2774/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3224/mongod     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3097/redis-server 0
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2774/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29048/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      29048/sshd      
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      3282/code
```

Что говорит о том что контейнеры открыты для доступа из вне.
Надо все закрыть и дать доступ только через локалхост.

Comment: Как вариант - iptables - не?

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич потому что я не гуру линукса, и если я не ошибаюсь то после перезапуска всего стека докер опять откроет это дело. Для этого есть явно адекватное решение придуманное для этой цели.

Comment: Откроет, если не прописать в rc.init например :) Но у Вас в конфиге написана одна подсеть, а открывается другая. Это скорее баг, с этим лучше всего бороться iptables.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это случаем не     network_mode: "host" ?
Если есть вариант поправить докер компос файл так чтоб доступ был только по локал хосу пример "localhost:8000" или "127.0.0.1:8000"
То буду рад вам поставить РЕПУ в верх , а через иптаблици ну уж муторно и долго для меня , для этого есть быстро и боле безболезненное решение.

Comment: В docker >= 17.06 это исправили и добавили новую цепочку которую docker не перезатирает при перезапуске. Пруф: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решилось тем что убрал

```
    network_mode: "host"
```

В всех сервисах , и в замен просто добавил линки на редис и монго.

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'

    volumes:
          - /bitnami/mongo:/bitnami

    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"

    environment:
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123

  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'

    volumes:
          - /bitnami/redis:/bitnami

    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:6379:6379'

    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=password123

  main:
    build: .

    links:
       - mongodb
       - redis

    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"

    volumes:
     - .:/code
     - /settings:/go/settings/

  dev:
    build: .

    links:
     - mongodb
     - redis

    ports:
     - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"

    volumes:
     - .:/code
     - /settings:/go/settings/
#
#volumes :
#  redis:
#    - /bitnami/redis
#  mongodb:
#    - /bitnami/mongo


root@localhost:/home/InterExchangeHustla# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2774/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8728/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8697/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12138/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2774/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29048/sshd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10258/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      29048/sshd
```